# rest_framework access objects of ManyToManyField in intermediate model

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a patient model. Each patient can have several "Medical Records" where choices come from models like "BodyPart" or "Medicin":

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Examination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BodyPart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Medicin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    examination = models.ForeignKey('Examination', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    part_of_body = models.ForeignKey('BodyPart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medicin = models.ManyToManyField('Medicin')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

Using Inlines we can nicely add Records to each Patient:

```
class MedicalRecordAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MedicalRecord
    extra = 1

class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Patient
    inlines = [MedicalRecordAdmin,]

...

admin.site.register(Patient, PatientAdmin)
...
```

Where I'm failing is (already tried `trough`, `serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)`, etc.), how can I serialize these relations from the side of the Patient Model?

```
# view
class PatientViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()

# serializer
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 3
```

ends in:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bert"
    }
]

## But I would expect something like:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bert",
        "medical_records":[
           [
             {
                 "medicine": ["a","b","c"],
                 "body_part": "leg",
                 "examination": "x-ray"
             }
           ],
           [
             {
                "medicine": ["e","f","g"],
                "body_part": "head",
                "examination": "surgery"
             }
           ],
         ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a nested serializer and use source fields to achieve the desired result.

[Nested relationships- DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Somewhat like this :

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
class Examination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
class BodyPart(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
class Medicin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
class MedicalRecord(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='patient_med')
    examination = models.ForeignKey('Examination', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='examination_med')
    part_of_body = models.ForeignKey('BodyPart', on_delete=models.CASCADE, relayted_name='part_of_body_med')
    medicin = models.ManyToManyField('Medicin', related_name='medicin_med')
    
    
    
    
class MedicalRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    body_part = serializers.CharField(source='part_of_body.name', read_only=True)
    examination = serializers.CharField(source='examination.name', read_only=True)
    medicine = serializers.ListField(source='medicine.name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = MedicalRecord
       fields = ('body_part', 'examination', 'medicine')
 
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    patient_med = MedicalRecordSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 3
```

Comment: Thanks a million coming for help @Neeraj. This is similar to what I've tried. Unfortunately, the result stays the same. The medical-record does not get rendered as a nested dependency. It looks there is some connection missing between Patient <--> medical record. By the way, I'm not fixed with this model solution. So in case, there is a simpler way of attaching infinite Records (consisting of BodyPart, Medicin, Examination) I'm all open ears ;)

Comment: Hey apologies, could you send the response you are getting after using nested serializer and excluding the medicine = serializers.ListField()

Comment: sure! https://0bin.net/paste/HDLPisQ1#jFb31UQ30v2o9Cafi2oiWPLf78rHOHZh4Dd5IFucnc6 I skip the URLs as it's just the default router which should not change anything! Find the resulting JSON at the bottom. Only the name, which is a field of Patient Model, get's serialized :/

Comment: The error might be because we haven't specified the source field which is why it isnt detecting medical_record from Patient model. Try changing the medical_records to : medical_records = MedicalRecordSerializer(source = 'patient_set', many=True, read_only=True).  Or you can change the models and set some related names for FK relations and use them.

Comment: this reads promising! Unfortunately doing so: https://0bin.net/paste/G+UB2lBl#8k-p1TN77z+GxDBZJqurWDDNXt2lzKW2rcWfCLomidm does not change it. :( "Or you can change the models and set some related names for FK relations and use them." Can you show me the way how I would do it? What a hard nut!

Comment: Update I've tried to set a related name: https://0bin.net/paste/HuLjA4KG#bDiGHtIewo3AWIoZn5uj5VvUOj-oFmnVA3raUT99V0m  no difference.

Comment: Try this https://0bin.net/paste/9I8mgGXR#EMGatBW5tRpkQk2vLJHwTULIrI2gC65Uk60XYLrjUmD.  Check if this returns patient_med in json response. Also please run the migrations first

Comment: you are the hero of the day! This does it and made my day! May I add two most likely very easy questions: https://0bin.net/paste/hykYr79+#+OZdP-6Ijf14Z69XrcmdbgqcMMtwXXhqZLwnhSxzgja Do you know why medicine is returning the ID and not the name? Further why the exclude of `medicine.patient` ends in an error that the field does not exist?

Comment: Boom got it working with another serializer! Yeah. thanks a million!

Comment: haha no problem! it returns id beucase if you check db Fk elements are stored as ids. If you want to get the name you have to traverse it

Comment: I've edited the answer response as well for other to skip the comments, do let me know if i've missed something